# How do I solve 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, windows-services

I have a Windows Service application. It is a very busy application. It is supposed to run continuously looking for things to do. After it runs for a while I get

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

It can happen at different times but usually a this paragraph:

Private Shared Function GetUnprocessedQueue() As Boolean

```
    Try



        Dim l_svcOOA As New svcITGOOA.IsvcITGOOAClient(OOAProcessing.cGlobals.EndPoint_ITGOOA)
        Dim l_iFilter As New svcITGOOA.clsFilter

        With l_svcOOA

            With l_iFilter


                .FilingType = OOAProcessing.cGlobals.FilingType

            End With
            m_ReturnClass = .itgWcfOOA(1, cGlobals.DatabaseIndicator, svcITGOOA.eOOAAction.GetUnprocessedQueue, l_iFilter, 71)
            Return CompletedGetUnprocessedQueue(m_ReturnClass)
        End With


    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionHandling(ex, "GetUnprocessedQueue " & m_Application)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

This is using a wcf service to read a queue. It reads the queue every two minutes to see if new records have been added to it.

Please help me solve this. I don’t know where to start.

Comment: Does any of those objects need to be disposed? (ie. do they implement IDisposable?)

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if they need to be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

The OutOfMemoryException exception occurs when the GC has completed a cycle of collection but the memory is not available even after that. I couldn't make out what the above code snippet does, but I think using Weak References for objects could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a timer that was generated within the same paragraph that I was setting

For example

```
 m_svcTimer = New Timers.Timer With {.Interval = m_Interval, .Enabled = True}
        AddHandler m_svcTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf StartTheQueueIfTime
        m_svcTimer.Enabled = True
        m_svcTimer.Start()
```

was within the paragraph StartTheQueueIfTime. I thought this would be a way to change the time interval. Instead it kept creating new events. Finally too many caused my crash.

Bob